# How to remove scrollbar in PrimeFaces dialog?

Tags: css, primefaces

I have ajax loading modal dialog in my webapp:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" minimizable="false" appendToBody="true"
    closable="false" header="Processing..." resizable="false" maximizable="false" style="overflow:hidden !important; overflow-x: hidden !important; width:auto;">  
     <p:graphicImage library="assets" name="ajax-loader.gif" style="overflow:hidden !important; overflow-x: hidden !important;"></p:graphicImage> 
</p:dialog>
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
```

No matter what CSS styles (I tried various combinations of overflow/overflow-x etc) I use it still displays horizontal (vertical is hidden, no problems there) scrollbar. I also played around with appendToBody attribute.

I need to disable the horizontal scrollbar.

EDIT: this is the HTML rendered by PrimeFaces

```
<div id="j_idt18" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-overlay-hidden" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: auto; left: 832px; top: 210px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 1003; display: block;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="j_idt18_title" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="off">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top">
<span id="j_idt18_title" class="ui-dialog-title">Processing...</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="height: auto;"><img id="j_idt19" src="/webapp/do/javax.faces.resource/ajax-loader.gif?ln=assets" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

I have been able to get rid of the scrollbar by overriding default dialog CSS in my own stylesheet:

```
.ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

However, this affects all dialogs, not just the ajax loading one. I want to be able to override that style on per-dialog basis. How do I do that?

Comment: And you you tried these styles?overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden; and also try vise versa.

Comment: @ComputerGeek, I have tried "overflow-y: scroll" - displays vertical scrollbar. Tried "overflow-x: hidden;", it does not hide horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: See if this link helps  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/cb31085a-fa4e-4f38-b111-74ea0236dfa5

Comment: and also see if any of the answers from this links work for you http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3623

Comment: iframe trick did not work. I do not want to start changing JQuery source - this is way to hacky and bound to break whenever I upgrade PrimeFaces. I added the rendered HTML in question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In you `statusDialog` dialog add `styleClass="disable-scroll"`.

Also, create CSS rule for this:

```
.disable-scroll .ui-dialog-content {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

This will apply CSS to all dialogs with this custom class.